# POSTing to an api

Tags: post, xamarin.android, httpwebrequest, httpclient, webclient

I can GET from my api, but I can not POST to. And it works with postman. so the server has no problem.
I had examine three ways: httpclient, httpwebrequest, webclient, but non of them works for me:

1:

```
        string data = "Name=mohammadi&BirthDate=1382-01-01&IsMarried=false&PersonId=16";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var stringContent = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var s = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
        var content = s.Result;
```

content says: "internal server error" and no exception throws

2:

```
        string data = "Name=mohammadi&BirthDate=1382-01-01&IsMarried=false&PersonId=16";
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        var str = w.OpenWrite(url, "POST");
        w.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var writer = new StreamWriter(str);
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Flush();
```

does not works and says nothing

3:

```
        string data = "Name=mohammadi&BirthDate=1382-01-01&IsMarried=false&PersonId=16";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
        }

        stream.Dispose();
```

does not works and says nothing

Comment: what shoud I set the url? I have set it to http:// ... /... /person/Add

Comment: and for GET I set it to .... /GetAll

Comment: My api method names are GetAll and Add

Comment: I think the ContentType of the post message does not set to urlencoded. because of the error of httpclient way.